# need explanation about a matlab code snippet about moran process

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab. I was reading this code snippet, but in some parts (marked with asterisks) I don't understand what it means, so if anybody could help would be very much appreciated

```
function [A1nmb] = moran(initsize, popsize) 
% MORAN generates a trajectory of a Moran type process 
%  which gives the number of genes of allelic type A1 in a population 
%  of haploid individuals that can exist in either type A1 or type A2.
%  The population size is popsize and the initial number of type A1 
%  individuals os initsize. 
%  Inputs: initsize - initial number of A1 genes
%          popsize - the total population size (preserved)

if (nargin==0)
  initsize=10;
  popsize=30;
end

A1nmb=zeros(1,popsize);
A1nmb(1)=initsize;

**lambda = inline('(x-1).*(1-(x-1)./N)', 'x', 'N');
mu = inline('(x-1).*(1-(x-1)./N)', 'x', 'N');**

x=initsize;
i=1;
while  (x>1 & x<popsize+1)
  if (lambda(x,popsize)/(lambda(x,popsize)+mu(x,popsize))>rand)
   x=x+1;
   A1nmb(i)=x;
  else
   x=x-1;
   A1nmb(i)=x;
  end;
  i=i+1;
end;
nmbsteps=length(A1nmb);
***rate = lambda(A1nmb(1:nmbsteps-1),popsize) ...
        +mu(A1nmb(1:nmbsteps-1),popsize);***  

**jumptimes=cumsum(-log(rand(1,nmbsteps-1))./rate);**
jumptimes=[0 jumptimes];

stairs(jumptimes,A1nmb);
axis([0 jumptimes(nmbsteps) 0 popsize+1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line you marked

```
lambda = inline('(x-1).*(1-(x-1)./N)', 'x', 'N');
```

creates something called an inline function. It is equivalent to defining a mathematical function. Example:

```
y = inline('x^2')
```

would allow you to do

```
>> y(2)
4
```

This immediately explains the second line you marked.

```
rate = lambda(A1nmb(1:nmbsteps-1),popsize) ...
    +mu(A1nmb(1:nmbsteps-1),popsize);
```

will compute the value of the function `lambda(x,N)` at `x = A1nmb(1:nmbsteps-1)` and `N = popsize`.

I will say immediately here that you should take a look at [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html), a different format used to accomplish the same as `inline`. Only, anonymous functions are generally better supported, and usually a lot faster than `inline` functions.

Then, for the final line,

```
jumptimes = cumsum(-log(rand(1,nmbsteps-1))./rate);
```

is a nested command. `rand` will create a matrix containing pseudorandom numbers, `log` is the natural logarithm (`"ln"`), and `cumsum` creates a new matrix, where all the elements in the new matrix are the cumulative sum of the elements in the input matrix.

You will find the commands `doc` and `help` very useful. Try typing

```
doc cumsum
```

or

```
help inline
```

on the Matlab command prompt. Try that again with the commands forming the previous statement.

As a general word of advice: spend *an **insane** lot of time* reading through the documentation. Really, for each new command you encounter, read about it and play with it in a sandbox until you feel you understand it. Matlab only becomes powerful if you know all its commands, and there are a **lot** to get to know.

Answer (score 0):

It defines an inline function object. For example this

```
 lambda = inline('(x-1).*(1-(x-1)./N)', 'x', 'N')
```

defines lambda as a function with 2 variables. When you call `lambda(A,n)` Matlab simply expands the function you define in the first string. Thus `lambda(A,n)` using the variables you provide in the function call. `lambda(A,n)` would will evaluate to:

```
 (A-1).*(1-(A-1)./n)
```

it just expands the function using the parameters you supply. Take a look at this link for more specific details http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/inline.html

The `cumsum` function just returns the cumulative sum of a matrix along a particular dimension. Say we call cumsum on a vector `X`, then the value at element `i` in the result is equal to the sum of elements in `X` from index 1 to `i`. For example `X = [1 2 1 3]` we would get

```
  AA = cumsum(X);
```

we would have

```
  AA = [1 3 5 8]
```

See this link for more details and examples http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/cumsum.html

Comment: One more question, in (A-1).*(1-(A-1))./n) , what is the meaning of that dot '.' in the equcation.   is the dot complusory